# How to Limit the number of decimals with out Rounding off in VBS/UFT

Tags: automated-testing, qtp, vbscript, uft

I want to limit the number of digits after decimal point, I am trying **"FormatNumber"** function but it's rounding the last number. Is there any other way to **"FormatNumber"** with out rounding off

e.g: `dbNum="1252.225522658695"`
and I am expecting number should come as `"1252.22552265`" means **8 digits after decimal with out rounding off**.

Answer (score 1):

bmshort will work for positive numbers but may give wrong output for negative numbers with your example.

Use Fix instead of Int which should work for both positive and negative numbers

```
Dim x : x = 1252.225522658695
Dim y : y = 8
print Fix (x * 10 ^ y)/10 ^ y
```

Output `1252.22552265`

Try to change x to `-1252.225522658695`, output would be `-1252.22552265`

Answer (score 0):

There is not a specific truncation function in VBScript but you could perform the following if x is your original number and y is the number of digits you wish to truncate to:

Int (x * 10 ^ y)/10 ^ y